# Get CMS page for the correct store view

Tags: cms

I have two store views, for 2 languages. 
I have a page 'foo' defined in both languages (i.e. store views). I'm using

```
$aCmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('foo', 'identifier');
```

However, I always get the page in the same language.

Shouldn't I get the page for the current store view?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You can use below code:

```
$identifier='foo';
    $page   = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
            $pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
            if ($pageId) {
               aCmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($pageId);
            }
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius!

Answer (score 1):

you have to set store id in call like

```
$cmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load('foo', 'identifier');
```

so it will load cms page per current store.

hope this will sure work for you.

Comment: Did not work ;(
Any other ideas?

Comment: Second that - using setStore does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use helper class `Mage_Cms_Helper_Page`'s method  `getPageUrl`, it gives the result of cms page URL  with the correct store view

```
Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($pageid);
```